# How Can I Apply Different Formats Based on Data Values

Tags: format, sas, sas-macro

I'm revising a data step that resides in a SAS macro.  Currently a single format is used to create a new field for the whole dataset.  I'm attempting to revise it to where a different format will be used on different subsets of the dataset.  (I have a field that indicates which subset the row belongs to.)

I could do this with a bunch of if statements, but that would need to be changed if the number of categories changes in the future.  I think I can achieve what I want by using call symput and resolve but I'm unsure what the syntax for that would be.  Can I achieve this without resorting to if statements?

Comment: Good question -- I am unsure the best way to make this dynamic.  +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't perfectly clear, but if you want to do something like

```
newvar = put(oldvar,MYFMT.)
```

->

```
if x=1 then newvar=put(oldvar,MYFMT.);
else newvar=put(oldvar,MYFMT2.);
```

But without all of the if statements, you can use `PUTN` or `PUTC`, which allows you to specify the format at runtime.

```
newvar = putn(oldvar,fmtvar); *optionally can specify w and d as separate arguments also;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, and using putc was much simpler than trying to use call symput and resolve.

Comment: Symput/resolve wouldn't work anyway; the format needs to be determined during the compilation stage if you are using `put`.